# Writing Unicode into PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, character-encoding

I have Unicode text (a sequence of Unicode codes) and a TTF font (bytes of a TTF file). I would like to write that text into a PDF file using that font.

I understand PDF quite well. I don't mind using two bytes per character. I would like to attach the TTF file as it is (charcode-to-glyf map should be used from a TTF file).

What font `Subtype` and `Encoding` value should I use? Is it possible to avoid having `ToUnicode` record?

I tried to use Subtype = "/TrueType", but it requires to specify FirstChar, LastChar and Widths (which are already inside TTF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Unicode with a **Font**, at all (except in the limited case of Latin, or nearly Latin, languages), because Fonts use an Encoding, and an Encoding is a single byte array. So you can't reference more than 256 characters from a Font, and a character code can't be more than a single byte.

The first problem with 'using Unicode' is that Unicode is not a simple 2-byte Encoding, its a multi-byte format, with variable lengths and sometimes a single glyph is represented by multiple Unicode code points.

So, in order to deal with this you need to use a CIDFont, not a Font. You cannot 'use the charcode-to-glyf map', by which I assume you mean the CMAP subtable in the TTF font. You must compose the CIDFont with a CMap in order to map the multiple bytes in the text string into the character codes for lookup in the CMap, which gives you the CID to reference the precise character program in the font.

It may be possible to construct a single CMap which would cover every Unicode code point, but I have my doubts, it would certainly be a huge task. However certain CMaps already exist. Adobe publish a standard list on their web site which includes CMaps such as UniCNS-UCS2-H and UniCNS-UCS2-V or UniGB-UTF8-H etc.

You can probably use one of the standard CMaps.

Note that it doesn't matter that the FirstChar, LastChar etc are already stored in the TrueType font, you still need to specify them in the PDF Font object. That's because a PDF consumer might not be rendering the text at all, it could (for example) be extracting the text, in which case it doesn't need to interpret the font provided this information is available.

Comment: Unicode is not a 2-byte Encoding, it is not an encoding at all. You probably meen UTF-8 or UTF-16?  So there is no way to avoid CIDFont, when I need more than 256 characters? Do you have any simple example of such PDF?

Comment: I'm aware that Unicode isn't an 'Encoding' in the sense that PDF uses it, that was rather the point I was making. To answer your additional questions; no you cannot avoid having a CIDFont if you want to reference more than 256 characters from a font. No I don't have a simpl eexample of a PDF using a CIDFont, but most modern software uses CIDFonts nowadays, so you should be able to find one easily enough. A Google for CIDFont +PDF might be enough. I missed this in the original question; ToUnicode CMaps are optional, you don't have to supply one ever. However cut+paste won't work if you don't.

Comment: @Ivan *"So there is no way to avoid CIDFont, when I need more than 256 characters?"* - you could alternatively use multiple simple fonts, each containing up to 256 glyphs, to emulate a larger font. In general, though, that would not be a good solution. And what's so bad about composite fonts after all?

Comment: Its a good point, but using multiple fonts doesn't address the original question of writing Unicode in a PDF file. In PostScript you could probably do something cunning wit the show operator to select the required font from an array of fonts, but you can't do that in PDF.